# Change datetime string format in request url when using Spring data rest with QuerydslPredicateExecutor

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, querydsl

In my domain class I have a field:

```
public class Reservation {
    private LocalDateTime created = LocalDateTime.now();
```

In my repository I want to find only Reservations with some specific date (time doesn't matter):

```
public interface ReservationRepository extends Repository<Reservation, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Reservation>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QReservation> {

        bindings.bind(root.created).first((path, value) -> path.between(value.withMinute(0).withHour(0), value.withMinute(0).withHour(0).plusDays(1).minusSeconds(1)));
    }
}
```

Now it works with this url:

```
/reservations?created=01/20/16 00:00 AM"
```

But I want to use this datatime format:

```
2016-01-20T00:00
```

As I understood the problem that Spring boot uses RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class for autoconfiguration. And by default TemporalAccessorParser.class uses some default DateTimeFormatter. And I want to change it to

```
DateTimeFormatter ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME
```

Comment: I'm not sure but try to add annotation `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm")` to the entity field `created`...

Comment: @Cepr0 I've tried. It didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only `@DateTimeFormat` annotation did not help, try to add to the project a custom [Converter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html):

```
public class CustomStringToLocalDateTime implements Converter<String, LocalDateTime> {

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convert(String source) {
        return LocalDateTime.parse(source);
    }
}

@Configuration
public class RepoRestConfig extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureConversionService(ConfigurableConversionService conversionService) {
        conversionService.addConverter(String.class, LocalDateTime.class, new CustomStringToLocalDateTime());
        super.configureConversionService(conversionService);
    }
}
```

Such an approach works in my project (except I had to convert string representation of date (`'yyyy-MM-dd'`) to `Instant` (`yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ`)).

Comment: Yes, it helped. I was thinking about a custom converte but didn't know how to correctly add it to configuration. Thanks!